# bash -declare documentation

Tags: linux, bash, declare

If you declare an array like this

```
declare -a test
```

you can echo the value like this

```
i=2
echo ${test[i]}
```

or

```
i="1+1" 
echo ${test[i]}
```

why the second form is accepted?
i need a complex answer thanks

Comment: complex answer needs complex question .

Answer (score 4):

See `man bash`:

> The subscript is treated as  an  arithmetic  expression that must evaluate to a number.

Complex enough?